# Finding the sum of first $N$ squares with generating functions

Tags: calculus, generating-functions

I'm trying to prove the well-known result
$$\sum_1^Nn^2=\frac{N(N+1)(2N+1)}6$$
using generating functions. The obvious choice is to set $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^N n^2x^n$, so that we have $$f(x)=(xD)^2\sum_1^N 1x^n=(xD)^2\left(\frac{x^{N+1}-1}{x-1}\right).$$
It seems like it should be easy to find $f(x)$, then setting $x=1$ to find $f(1)$ should be a slam-dunk. Indeed, the text I'm referring to says that direct evaluation is the way and that "after doing two differentiations and a lot of algebra the answer emerges". Somehow, I can't do this. [In particular, I get that](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(x%20(-1%20-%20x%20%2B%20x%5En%20(1%20%2B%20n%20(-2%20%2B%20n%20(-1%20%2B%20x))%20(-1%20%2B%20x)%20%2B%20x)))%2F(-1%20%2B%20x)%5E3&lk=1&assumption=%22ClashPrefs%22%20-%3E%20%7B%22Math%22%7D)
$$f(x)=\frac{xp(x)}{(x-1)^3},$$
where $p$ is a polynomial of degree $n$, and the $(x-1)$s at the denominator does not cancel with anything in the numerator. I'm puzzled how I'm now supposed to substitute $x=1$, since we end up dividing by zero. Can someone help?

Comment: What does the $(xD)^2$ notation mean?

Comment: @TomGrubb $D$ is the differentiation operator (understood to be with respect to $x$).  The equation says that $f(x)$ is the result of differentiating the sum, multiplying by $x$, differentiating again and multiplying again.

Comment: @FredH indeed, that's what I meant by $xD$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
f(x)
&=(xD)^2\left(\frac{x^{N+1}-1}{x-1}\right)\\
&=(xD)(xD)\left(\frac{x^{N+1}-1}{x-1}\right)\\
&=x\left(xD\left(\frac{x^{N+1}-1}{x-1}\right)+D^2\left(\frac{x^{N+1}-1}{x-1}\right)\right)\\
&=x^2D\left(\frac{x^{N+1}-1}{x-1}\right)+xD^2\left(\frac{x^{N+1}-1}{x-1}\right)
\end{align}
If $t=x-1$:
\begin{align}
\frac{x^{N+1}-1}{x-1}
&=\frac{(t+1)^{N+1}-1}t\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{N+1}\binom{N+1}kt^{k-1}
\end{align}
hence
\begin{align}
&\lim_{x\to 1}D\left(\frac{x^{N+1}-1}{x-1}\right)=\binom{N+1}2&
&\lim_{x\to 1}D^2\left(\frac{x^{N+1}-1}{x-1}\right)=2\binom{N+1}3&
\end{align}
thus
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 1}f(x)
&=\binom{N+1}2+2\binom{N+1}3\\
&=\frac{(N+1)N}2+\frac{(N+1)N(N-1)}3\\
&=\frac{3(N+1)N+2(N+1)N(N-1)}6\\
&=\frac{(N+1)N(2N+1)}6
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Just apply *L'Hopital's rule* 3 times to resolve your singularity. I will not write out the details in full $f(1) = \lim_{x \to 1}\frac{xp(x)}{(x-1)^3} =  \frac{(D)^3(xp(x))} {6}$ where $D$ is the differential operator in your notation.